# any idea to solve "Linker error" undefiend reference

Tags: c++

```
enter code here
```

i am using dev c++ for my programming. as i am using some library developed on dev c++ i want to use the same compiler.

for my own dev project, i wanted some new classes. so i have added 2 classes `"TriangleLists, TriangleList"` (h file and cpp files) to the library. when i compiled the library it worked without any error and able to create new library file. but, when i am compiling my own project i got the linker error problem.

```
[Linker error] undefined reference to `TriangleLists::Erase()' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `TriangleList::TriangleList(TriangleList const&)' 
[Linker error] undefined reference to `TriangleList::operator=(TriangleList const&)' 
ld returned 1 exit status
```

actually, in the library there were similar classes called `RectangleList, RectangleLists`.. so, i copied those 2 classes and modify to fit with my class `TriangleList`.

any suggestion to solve this please. thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you added the source files containing the implementations for these to the build?

Comment: Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: This question is very hard to answer. You have described what *happened*, but not what you *did*. Please show what you have done.

Comment: @GregHewgill: He _tried to add new few classes to the library_!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Why do you assume that one must be using a book if one is learning to code? Did you actually mean to recommend using a book? That would be appropriate, I guess.

Comment: @ all, sorry for the inconveniences. i have amended the post.

Comment: @NiklasB.: The feigned assumption is a mechanism for adding extreme emphasis to the recommendation. A cognate to the great British power of sarcasm, I suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is class `TriangleLists` made by you or does it belong to the library?

Often a class object is not intended to be copied, and just cannot be done. To prevent library users to copy uncopyable objects creator may declare copy constructor and assignment operator (usually as private), but omit the the definition. If this is the case then just don't copy objects, and don't use them in a way that involves copying (like putting them in some `std` container). You **may** create objects on the heap and put pointers to those objects to a container.

EDIT: If those are your classes then answer is simple. Add function `Erase` to class `TriangleLists` and add copy constructor and assignment operator to class `TriangleList`. Since you're copying functionality from similar class `RectangleList` search for its copy constructor and assignment operator, `RectangleList::RectangleList(RectangleList const&)` and `RectangleList::operator=(RectangleList const&)`.

Comment: I am not sure, i undestood you correctly as my c++ basics are very low. (anyway, yes TriangleLists and TriangleList are the new classes i have added to the lib.) actually, in the library there were similar classes called RectangleList, RectangleLists.. so, i did the same way as it were and modifed the function with respect to TriangleList class...may be if you say simple way what to do, then it is really helpful. thank you